# org-export-hook does not trigger

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

When exporting an org file to Latex / HTML / etc. I want to replace every occurrence of "Hello" with "World"

```
(add-hook 'org-export-preprocess-final-hook
      (lambda () (replace-string "Hello" "World")))
```

Setting the hook doesn't seem to do anything, nothing gets replaced in the exported file. Do I use the wrong hook?

Comment: Which version of org-mode are you using? (Perhaps an older version doesn't provide that hook?)

Comment: Apparently version 8.2

Answer (score 2):

I tried and it worked for me.

Typed your exact line and executed it (using `C-x e` in my scratch buffer)

Confirmation, using `C-h v org-export-preprocess-final-hook`

```
org-export-preprocess-final-hook's value is ((lambda nil
     (replace-string "Hello" "World")))
```

Tested from a buffer containing

```
* Task
Hello
Bouh
Hello
```

Using `M-x org-export` then `H` (temporary buffer), I got (snippet)

```
<p>World
Bouh
World
</p></div>
```

Are you sure you executed your registration ?

Comment: Tried by using `C-c C-e L` (for latex in temp buffer), seemed to have work as well. I used M-x org-export cause I did not remember the shortcut. Have you tried looking at the content of the `'org-export-preprocess-final-hook`variable using `C-h v` to be sure your hook was properly registered ?

Comment: Yep, C-h v org-export-preprocess-final-hook gives me the same result you got.

Comment: No clue except that it works for me, sorry, I can't reproduce the problem hence can't help :-/